# I need feedback on footers if it sticks on the bottom of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can I get a feedback on my footers from my 3 works i dont know if the footers are sticked to bottom on large screen resolutions. please check it for me pls. View it at full page. Thank you.

http://goo.gl/nUrT6m

Comment: thanks for down voting and im sorry that im unaware of those. Managed to find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha ... it's awesome you asked. Yes, no and no.

Comment: thanks i will make modifications for the 2. I appreciate your help awesome!